# drop shadow effect css

Tags: html, css

I only want to display the shadow effect without the square itself.

[image]

here is the block code:

```
.light-blur-effect {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #BEEEF5;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 20px #BEEEF5);
}
```

The only thing that came to mind is to do through opacity, but as you may guess, it didn’t help

Comment: Post your html code too so that the answerers can work on it and eventually come up with a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    .light-blur-effect {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #BEEEF5;
    filter: blur(3px);
    opacity: 0.4;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-blur-effect">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `drop shadow` effect you can use `box-shadow` effect it is working completely fine it is only droping `shadow` and the size and direction of the shadow which you want you can easily modify in `box-shadow`

```css
.light-blur-effect {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    opacity: 0.4;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #BEEEF5;

}
```

```html
<div class="light-blur-effect">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the solution from the top fits my situation perfectly